# I ask for a number in this code, what should I do in case the user gives a letter instead?

Tags: c++, c++11

The problem is what should I do to prevent the user to put a char instead of a number in floats h,a,b,A or B

I've tried using typeid, but I don't know how that works

```
int main() {
  float h, a, b, A, B;
  std::cout << "Llena los datos, si no tienes algún dato, escribe 0\n";
  std::cout<<"Hipotenusa:";
  std::cin >> h;
  std::cout<<"Lado a: ";
  std::cin>> a;
  std::cout<<"Lado b: ";
  std::cin>> b;
  std::cout<<"Angulo A: ";
  std::cin>> A;
  std::cout<<"Angulo B: ";
  std::cin>> B;
}

If the user gives a char value for one of the variables, I expect an output of "Incorrect Value", which is "Datos Incorrectos" in spanish.
```

Comment: You can't prevent the user from doing anything. The only thing you can do is implement proper error checking, and take some sensible action upon invalid input.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way but not the best, Just you want a loop which takes the input then check whether the input is a number or not and if not, prints the input message again until the user input a number.

```
float Number;
cout << "Please enter a number: ";
while (!(cin >> Number)) {
    cout << "Error: Please enter a number: ";
    // clears the error flag
    cin.clear();
    // Throw away a specific number of characters from the input stream
    cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
}
```

Comment: Exceedingly unlikely, but there may be more than `INT_MAX` characters in the stream. If you're going `INT_MAX`, you might as well go the distance with `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()`

Answer (score 0):

Look at my else if statement.  It doesnt include variable declarations.

```
    {
        cout << "Input correct sales tax ( .08 or .12 for example. ) : ";
        cin >> salesTax;
        if ((salesTax < 0)||(salesTax > 1))
        {
            cout << invalid << endl << "\nRestarting...\n";
            fnInitiateRegister();
            return 0;   
        }
        else if (cin.fail()) // HERE IS YOUR ANSWER
        {
            cout << invalid << "Needs to be a numeric value.\n";
            return 0;
        }  // HERE IS WHERE YOUR ANSWER ENDS.  
        else
        {
            cout << "Proceeding to cart\n";
            fnNumberOfCartItems();
        }   return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Fails to clear the error flag and remove the bad input.